# How can I make toggable divs for multiple choices, if possible using jquery and/or bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, widget, multiple-choice

I'd like to make a beautiful multiple choice HTML page.  I want to have 3 or 4 `<div>`s including images and/or text, and users should be able to toggle each `<div>` "on" or "off" by simply clicking anywhere on the `<div>` (there should be a highlighting effect, if possible with an animation).  When the form gets submitted, the server should be sent the state of each `<div>`, as if it were a checkbox.

I have searched all over the place but could not find something like that.  It seems so basic that I probably overlooked something trivial.  Any ideas?  I already use jQuery and bootstrap, so if there's a simple solution based only on these frameworks, I'd be very happy.

Thanks.

**Edit:** I don't want the `<div>`s to move or disappear.  I just want a "highlighting" effect, such as changing the background color to blue when the `<div>` is selected, and back to white when it is unselected.

Comment: Will this work? http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Something like the bootstrap collapsible? http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse you of course would need custom code to send the state of the divs with a form submit.

Comment: @Scott: Well, toggle seems to show/hide instead of highlighting/"un-highlighting", so not really what I need, although there are some things in common.

Comment: @KevinB: mmmh, not exactly, I probably need to clarify my question, I'm sorry.  I'll edit it.

Comment: Ah, you don't want to collapse them, you simply want it either highlighted or not highlighted. That should be as simple as a click event that adds/removes (.toggleClass) a class to/from the clicked div while also updating a hidden input with div status. You don't need a plugin for that.

Comment: @KevinB: I guess that's why I'm confused.  It seems so simple that I expected it to be a basic widget, but I cannot find it anywhere.  Would you mind spelling out your suggestion in an answer? I'd be happy to vote for it if there's no better solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend starting with a good HTML base. I would probably use a hidden radio button inside each `div` and check or uncheck it when the `div` was clicked. The radio button would be a valid item on the form which would submit the selected value.

HTML:

```
<div class="choice">
    <input id="choice_1" type="radio" name="choice" value="choice_1" />
    <label for="choice_1">Chicago</label>
</div>

<div class="choice">
    <input id="choice_2" type="radio" name="choice" value="choice_2" />
    <label for="choice_2">Los Angeles</label>
</div>


<div class="choice">    
    <input id="choice_3" type="radio" name="choice" value="choice_3" />
    <label for="choice_3">San Francisco</label>
</div>
```

​JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var choices = $('.choice');

    choices.on('click', function(event) {
        var choice = $(event.target);
        choice
            .find('[name="choice"]')
            .prop('checked', true)
            .trigger('change');
    });

    var inputs = $('.choice input');
    inputs.on('change', function(event) {
        var input = $(event.target);
        var choice = $(this).closest('.choice');

        $('.choice.active').removeClass('active');
        choice.addClass('active');
    });
});​
```

Demo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cYhTX/)

## Alternative: if you want multiple selected at once

So with radio buttons only one within the radio button group is active at a time. If that is not the behavior you want, you could use a hidden checkbox and toggle it on and off.

HTML:

```
<div class="choice">
    <input id="choice_1" type="checkbox" name="choice_1" value="choice_1" />
    <label for="choice_1">Chicago</label>
</div>

<div class="choice">
    <input id="choice_2" type="checkbox" name="choice_2" value="choice_2" />
    <label for="choice_2">Los Angeles</label>
</div>


<div class="choice">    
    <input id="choice_3" type="checkbox" name="choice_3" value="choice_3" />
    <label for="choice_3">San Francisco</label>
</div>
```

​JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var choices = $('.choice');

    choices.on('click', function(event) {
        var choice = $(event.target);
        var input = choice.find('[type="checkbox"]');
        input
            .prop('checked', !input.is(':checked'))
            .trigger('change');
    });

    var inputs = $('.choice input');
    inputs.on('change', function(event) {
        var input = $(event.target);
        var choice = $(this).closest('.choice');

        if (input.is(':checked')) {
            choice.addClass('active');
        }
        else {
            choice.removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});​
```

Demo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DstkX/)

Comment: +1, though he didn't say anything about only one div being active at a time. I removed my answer because this one is much better other than that.

Comment: @KevinB Good point -- I'm assuming... I'll update the answer though for the other case.

Comment: Thanks a lot people, you were a great help.  Just one thing: I have images in my divs, and with this current code, clicking on the images does not select the div.  Replacing "var choice = $(event.target);" by "var choice = $(this).closest('.choice');" fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this a couple of ways using a jQuery click function:

```
// Toggle a class for the div
// - For this you would setup your styles in the CSS for your site 
$('div').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
});

// Animate the background-color for the div
// - For this you would need to include the jquery.color plugin
// - https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color
$('div').toggle(function(){
    $(this).animate({backgroundColor: "#aa0000"}, 500);
}, function(){
    $(this).animate({backgroundColor: "#ffffff"}, 500);
});
```

here's an example jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PC5ry/